# How to understand pointer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

```
Fraction* myFraction=[Fraction new];
[myFraction method];
```

`myFraction` is a pointer, it assigned with the memory address. When use the method of `myFraction`, shouldn't it be used `* myFraction`？

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Objective-C takes care of dereferencing the pointer for you when you use square bracket call syntax.

Comment: In general, pointers referencing Objective C objects are never dereferenced explicitly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank you !

Comment: @clemens thank you !

Comment: @RanJi That example comes from Kochan's ObjC book, doesn't it?  If so, toss the book in the trash and grab something more recent.  It was an OK book when it was written, but it is now way, way, out of date and you'll be very confused if you try to apply what you learn from it to modern iOS/Cocoa programming

Comment: @bbum I've got a copy of *Learning Cocoa* by O'Reilly Media lying around here somewhere, if you want it. ;-)

Comment: @bbum Yes, but maybe it is enough for a newbie...and do you have some recommendations

Comment: @RanJi What you learn from Kochan will no longer be applicable.  It'd be like learning how to program against iOS 2.0 and then being dropped into the current system.  You aren't going to know which way is up.   I'd recommend the Stanford courses and whatever tutorials are available via developer.apple.com.  Swift playgrounds are good, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking of C. Instead, Objective-C is actually dynamically dispatched, meaning that you don't actually call functions on Objective-C objects. Rather, you "send a message" to an instance. The Objective-C runtime handles the actual translation of that message into a C function call.

In your example, `[myFraction method]` actually compiles into something similar to `objc_msgSend(myFraction, @selector(method))`.

The `objc_msgSend()` function is the heart of Objective-C. It is hand [written in assembly](https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/master/runtime/Messengers.subproj/objc-msg-arm64.s#L252-L282) for each supported platform. Within this assembly call, the runtime will determine the type of the instance – `Fraction` in this case – and search the known instance methods on the Fraction Class. If no method is found, it will then search the superclass of Fraction all the way up to the root (`NSObject`).

Once the appropriate C-function for `-[Fraction method]` is identified, `objc_msgSend` will invoke it for you.

Interestingly, the resulting C function call is actually provided with two additional arguments (the `myFraction` pointer, and the original method selector). These are pulled off and stored in `self` and `_cmd` prior to executing the code you wrote in `-[Fraction method]`. This is how instance state is conveyed to instance functions! Pretty cool :)

Some reading:

https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-11-16-lets-build-objc_msgsend.html

Comment: First ,thank you for helping me. But forgive me my poor English... I can only understand a part of them. From your answer,  OC is different from C. I just send message to my instance, not call a function like C. So  I don't need think about pointer problem. Is that right?

Comment: That I mostly correct. Objective-C is built _on top of_ C. `myFraction` is a C pointer! However when you use the format `[myFraction ...]` the compiler changes it to C-compatible code.

Comment: Hey @RanJi, if this answer is helpful to you, would you mind marking it as "Accepted"?

Comment: @RanJi - Thank you!